# lotus notes automation

Tags: lotus-notes

Is it possible to automate lotus notes to post a local file to a database? I have a daily task to post a logfile to a notes database. I can gather the logfile via script but don't know enough about notes scripting to figure this out.

I know thrre is a com interface as long as I have the client on the PC, but I can't figure out how to get a file uploaded to a dataase.  I can use either vbscript or (preferred) powershell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you search around the net you'll find examples of using VBScript to manipulate Lotus Notes.  Here's one example:  http://haveworld.blogspot.com/2006/10/vbscript-and-lotus-notes.html

You'll need to know a little about Lotus Notes to make this work, though.  Start small and see if you can even get the Notes Version to appear:

```
Set oNotesSession = CreateObject("Notes.Notessession") 'create notes session
Msgbox oNotesSession.NotesVersion
```

If that works, you know you're in good shape.  If not, make sure you've installed Lotus Notes correctly and configured it on the client.

The code to post a local file to a database involves connecting to Notes, creating a new Notes Document, adding a file object into the body of the document, and then saving it.  You can use any kind of Notes Database to do this, but I'd suggest creating a new one based on the Document Library template, and using that to store your files.

Here is some code that will create a new Notes document, set the subject field, attach a file, and then save the document.  This assumes there's a local Notes database already available called "FileStorage.nsf"

```
strFileName = "C:\Windows\Media\tada.wav"
strSubject = "Your Subject Goes Here"

Set oNotesSession = CreateObject("Notes.Notessession") 'create notes session
Set oDb = oNotesSession.GetDatabase("", "FileStorage.nsf") 'open database on local named FileStorage.nsf
Set oDoc = oDb.CreateDocument

' Filling the fields
oDoc.Subject = strSubject
Set oBody = oDoc.CreateRichTextItem("Body")
oBody.EmbedObject 1454, "", strFileName   '1454 = Embedded Attachment type

oDoc.Save False, False
```

Comment: thanks I'll try this as soon as I can.  I have to use an existing notes database, is all I need the database name to use getdatabase?

Comment: Yes.  That first parameter is the server name, but if you're using a local database you can just leave that set to the empty string.  If your database is within a folder, you'll need the path from the data directory, so use GetDatabase("", "myfolder\filestorage.nsf")